# `ProxyComponent` has no propType for native prop `RCTMap.followUserLocation` of native type `BOOL`

Tags: ios, react-native

I recently upgraded RN from v0.19 to v0.22.

When I run the simulator, this error popped up.

[Simulator Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUChW.png)

Error log that shows in the xcode:

`` 2016-03-23 13:54:20.818 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] `ProxyComponent` has no propType for native prop `RCTMap.followUserLocation` of native type `BOOL`
If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.
2016-03-23 13:54:20.819 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.React.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: `ProxyComponent` has no propType for native prop `RCTMap.followUserLocation` of native type `BOOL`
If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.
2016-03-23 13:54:20.845 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Running application "________" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
2016-03-23 13:54:20.847 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Application ________ has not been registered. This is either due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.
2016-03-23 13:54:20.848 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.React.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Application IOS_99GAMERS has not been registered. This is either due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent. ``

I've removed the node_modules and reinstall v0.22.
Same error occurred.

I've been looking for a fix to this issue (thought I'm not the only one). But I couldn't find reported bug that's related to this issue.

I'm currently running on:
React Native v0.22,
xcode ios simulator,
Mac

If you need more detail, I'll reply within minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this making the same upgrade. The fix for us was to run a build from localhost first (the error was happening running a build using an offline bundle (refs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#using-offline-bundle)